# Make custom/call skitter slideshow navigation

Tags: jquery, navigation, skitter-slider

For those of you who worked with Skitter Slideshow, it's a great plugin but I want to make custom next/prev buttons and place them outside of the .box_skitter container and call the skitter navigation function.

I tried creating the following:

```
// Custom Navigation
enable_custom_navigation: true,

if (self.settings.enable_custom_navigation) {
self.enableCustomNavigation();
}


enableCustomNavigation: function() {
var self = this;
$('#custom_next, #prev_button').click(function ()  {
// Next
if (this.id == 'custom_next') {
self.box_skitter.find('.next_button').trigger('click');
}
// Prev
else if (this.id == 'custom_prev') {
self.box_skitter.find('.prev_button').trigger('click');
}
});
},
```

Comment: do you have a example in jsfiddle or is this not possible?

Comment: @stefan kinda managed to assemble it into a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/brilliancedisplay/5tq6ut6n/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for the moment my solution is to create a next button and when clicked simulate a click on the predefined skitter .next_button, like so:

```
$(document).on('click', '.next', function(event) { 
    event.preventDefault(); 
    $(".box_skitter .next_button").click(); 
});
```